# Unexpected value DecoratorFactory imported by the module DynamicTestModule. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-unit-test

I'm writing unit tests for an Angular component. When I attempted to run it, I received the following error: "Error: Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation." Is there anything missing or wrong with my code?

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AlertController, NavController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { GlobalProvider } from 'src/app/services/app/global';
import { AccountProvider } from 'src/app/services/profile/account';
import { phoneValidation } from 'src/helpers/custom-validators';
import { AccountDetailsPage } from "./account-details";

describe("AccountDetailsPage", () => {
  let component: AccountDetailsPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountDetailsPage>;
  let accountProvider: AccountProvider;
  let formBuilder: FormBuilder;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AccountDetailsPage],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: accountProvider, useValue: {} }
      ],
      imports: [
        Component,
        NavController,
        ToastController,
        AlertController,
        AccountProvider,
        GlobalProvider,
        FormGroup,
        FormBuilder,
        Validators,
        phoneValidation,
        HttpClient
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountDetailsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('method1', () => {
    it('should ...', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have a provider inside of the `imports` array or vice versa. Remove `Component` from `imports` and maybe move it inside of `declarations` if it's an array. Move `NavController, ToastController, AlertController, AccountProvider, FormBuilder, Validators, phoneValidation` outside of the `imports` array and maybe move them to `providers`.

`imports` => should only have modules (@NgModule())

`providers` => should only have services and service like stuff (@Injectable())

`declarations` => should only have components, pipes and directives (@Component(), @Pipe(), @Directive())

Comment: so concretly for the OP case, what shoud be moved and where?

Comment: For OP's case, everything that's in the `imports` needs to be removed. `Component` needs to be moved to `declarations`, everything ending in `Controller` should be moved to `providers`, everything ending in `Provider` should be moved to `providers` and `Validators` and `phoneValidation` are not required anywhere. `HttpClient` should be swapped for `HttpClientTestingModule`. Here is a great resource on testing with Angular: https://testing-angular.com/ but the concepts of `imports`, `declarations`, and `providers` is Angular specific and not unit testing Angular specific.

Comment: you repeat same text as in your answer... however, the providers needs value and provider, not really clear what exactly the code should like

Answer (score 0):

you should not import NgModule because it is a decorator not a module.solved after delete NgModule from imports.